# Replace Referenced files with Symlink

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link

I have a git repo I am working with that has files and folders that need to be symlink to files and folders inside another folder. All of the symlinks are refrenced as text in the second projects folder. I am just wanting to know how to go through and have all the symlinks automatically setup.

Example Structure

`project1/`

`---- myfile.rb`

`---- myfolder/`

`project2/`

`---- myfile.rb`

`---- myfolder`

---

and in the file **project2/myfile.rb** it only includes the following text on line 1.

`../project1/myfile.rb`

and **project2/myfolder** just includes the text

`../project1/myfolder`

This is repeated throughout the file structure. Another example would be

**project2/app.rb** has the text

`../project2/app.rb`

I am on Ubuntu and thinking there is a way to go through these in an automated way and set the symlinks rather than manually finding each one.

Answer (score 1):

Not that git can version symlinks, so consider versioning the symlinks rather than such files. Also, you might want to consider git submodules so there is an actual relation between the two repositories.

If I got your question/setup right, this might do the trick. It searches for files (recursively) in folder `./project2` with line count of one and replaces each of those files with a link to the file named in there, given that the target exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(find project2/ -type f )
do
  linecount=$(wc -l $file | awk '{print $1}')
  if [ $linecount -eq 1 ]; then
    target=$(cat $file)
    relTarget=$(dirname $file)/$target
    if [ -f $relTarget ] || [ -d $relTarget ]; then
      rm $file
      ln -s $target $file
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: Well that's a bit less of a hack than what I was posting. But you don't support filenames that contain the newline character xD

Answer (score 0):

Run the following from inside your `project2` directory:

```
for file in *; do
    link="$(cat "$file")"
    rm "$file"
    ln -s "$link" "$file"
done
```

This isn't recursive, so it doesn't look into subdirectories.